# Multiple Bootstrap modals with different buttons link to respective content not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

As you can see I'm new to Stack so please excuse any mistake.

I'm making a Business site for my friend in Bootstrap3, on our(company) team page we have many members so i would like to have each members more details in modals with button.

I used modal sample code from w3c site modified it now when i use it on different members profile box only first persons modal works but rest modals not working.

Here is only one modal working code.
CSS

```
<style>
    /* The Modal (background) */
    .modal {
        display: none; /* Hidden by default */
        position: absolute; /* Stay in place */
        z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
        padding-top: 50px; /* Location of the box */
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%; /* Full width */
        height: 100%; /* Full height */
        overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
        background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
    }

    /* Modal Content */
    .modal-content {
        position: relative;
        background-color: #fefefe;
        margin: auto;
        padding: 0;
        border: 1px solid #888;
        width: 98%;
        box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
        -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
        animation-name: animatetop;
        animation-duration: 0.4s
    }

    /* Add Animation */
    @-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
        from {top:-300px; opacity:0} 
        to {top:0; opacity:1}
    }

    @keyframes animatetop {
        from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
        to {top:0; opacity:1}
    }

    /* The Close Button */
    .close {
        float: right;
        font-size: 28px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .close:hover,
    .close:focus {
        color: #000;
        text-decoration: none;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .modal-header {
        padding: 10px 2px 0px 2px;
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: bold;

    }

    .modal-body {padding: 2px 2px;}

    }
</style>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="center">
                            <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="ourteam-image">
                                <img src="images/portfolio/thumb/person1.gif" alt="">
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                <h4>Person 1</h4>
                                <h5>Director</h5>
                                <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae.</p>
                                <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" id="myBtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1">Open Modal</button>

                                <!-- The Modal -->
                                <div id="myModal1" class="modal">

                                  <!-- Modal content -->
                                  <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                    <span class="close">×</span>
                                    <p>Person 1</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae.</p>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                                </div>                  
                            </div><!--/panel-->
                        </div><!--/center-->
                    </div><!--/col-->

                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="center">
                            <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="ourteam-image">
                                <img src="images/portfolio/thumb/person2.gif" alt="">
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                <h4>Person 2</h4>
                                <h5>Director</h5>
                                <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae.</p>
                                <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" id="myBtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">Open Modal</button>

                                <!-- The Modal -->
                                <div id="myModal2" class="modal">

                                  <!-- Modal content -->
                                  <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                    <span class="close">×</span>
                                    <p>Person 2</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae.</p>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                                </div>                  
                            </div><!--/panel-->
                        </div><!--/center-->
                    </div><!--/col-->

                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="center">
                            <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="ourteam-image">
                                <img src="images/portfolio/thumb/person3.gif" alt="">
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                <h4>Person 3</h4>
                                <h5>Director</h5>
                                <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae.</p>
                                <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" id="myBtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal3">Open Modal</button>

                        <!-- The Modal -->
                                <div id="myModal3" class="modal">

                                  <!-- Modal content -->
                                  <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                    <span class="close">×</span>
                                    <p>Person 3</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae.</p>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                                </div>                  
                            </div><!--/panel-->
                        </div><!--/center-->
                    </div><!--/col-->
```

**Script**

```
// Get the modal
    var modal = document.getElementById('myModal1','myModal2','myModal3');

    // Get the button that opens the modal
    var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

    // When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
    btn.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "block";
    }

    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    span.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }

    // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
    window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (event.target == modal) {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
</script>
```

[Desire Output for all members](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EaPX0.png)

Sorry for lengthy post but just want to make it clear. 
Any Help or corrections would be really great.
Thanks

Comment: `document.getElementById('myModal1','myModal2','myModal3')` ? You can't do this..

Comment: Your code does work fine without the need of javascript... There're only two small issues - Remove `z-index` in `.modal` CSS, and add `data-dismiss="modal"` attribute to your `close` buttons. That's it, no scripts needed. Check [JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/8schp8g4/)

Comment: Thank you both for quick reply.
@ARTUR-FILIPIAK Is it possible that some other messing with modal bcoz JSFiddle work but same code in my page doesn't even i created new page with just JSFiddle code still its not working.

Comment: any errors in console?

Comment: no error just seems like buttons doesn't work without script but with script only first modal work by using `document.getElementById('myModal1')`. Is there any way around to use this line with every modal like generic?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it working by just adding bootstrap.min.js script link in header.
Thanks all this is now a fully working code.
I'll edit above code for future reference if anyone like me needed.